# Joy node doesn't work well

Tags: ros, ubuntu, joy-node, ubuntu-precise, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

I am trying to use an Xbox joystick with the joy node in a virtual machine. Although I've checked the correct joystick signals reception as shown in [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick) with `sudo jstest /dev/input/js1`; I've changed correctly the permissions; and I've set the ros param to the correct device (js1), but the node has problems to publish the data.
If I run the test as the tutorial tells, it takes some minutes before the first `rostopic echo /joy` received. Once I receive the echo, the values seems to be correct.
This problem increases when I launch that joy node with a several other nodes, in that case, I never get the echo response of the /joy topic.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS with ROS fuerte on a virtual machine using VirtualBox, and It doesn't seems to have any processor, I/O, or RAM problems (I run it together with Gazebo, rviz, etc.).

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52819/joy-node-doesn%27t-work-well/) by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-20**:
When you say it doesn't seem to have any processor, I/O or RAM problems, you mean nothing else is slow? If all that is happening is the /joy topic takes long to get published to, I would assume it is a problem of hardware virtualization and/or excessive swapping. Could you try it outside the VM?

**Comment by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on 2013-01-20**:
Testing the joystick with a test like "jstest", running on the virtual machine, everything works fine. Using ROS, everything seems to work fine, even gazebo and graphic rendering programs. The problem starts using /joy node. (Other nodes or programs work fine running at the same time than /joy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I got the solution without finding the failure...

I've reinstalled the whole system again and now it seems to work.

---

Originally posted by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) with karma: 74 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tlanglot](https://answers.ros.org/users/14301/tlanglot/) on 2014-04-09**:
In order to change the ros param, you have to go to the xbox360_teleop.launch and add

`< param name="dev" value="/dev/input/js1"/ >`

to the joy node.

**Comment by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on 2014-04-18**:
The question was closed more than one year ago. Thanks.